# Problems with raycasting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a food system for my game.

I want it to use a `Raycast` so you can pick it up, but I cant get it to work.  When I click on the object with the tag it doesn't work.

```
public Text FoodUI;
public int FoodAmount;
public float Distance;
public GameObject Hands;

void Start()
{
    FoodUI.text = "Food: " + FoodAmount;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
   RaycastHit hit;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag.Equals("Food"))
            {
                FoodAmount += 40;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing an opening brace for the `Physics.Raycast` if statement.

Comment: dont thinks thats it man i will try

Comment: Add `Debug.Logs` to check if your raycasting works, e.g. one after the raycast (and before tag check) and one in the tag check.

Comment: nope that werent the problem

Comment: Those braces would have caused errors anyways.

Comment: @FatihTkale Are you trying to have the player pick up the food when the mouse is clicked or 'E' key?

Comment: ray casting works it just also selects the floor somehow

Comment: @Enfyve yes im also making a inventory so yes

Comment: lol it looks like the floor had the tag

Comment: but i still cant get the add system work somehow

Comment: You can set up a raycast so it ignores certain layers. E. g. everything except a food layer.

Comment: Does the food object have a collider on it that's enabled?

Comment: Is `FoodAmount` updating in the inspector? You don't change the `text` component (`FoodUI.text`) right now so that one definitly can't update.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest to make the ray and the hit private fields and move their assignment into the first if so you only do something with them when you actually need it.

Comment: I fixed everything thanks for your time!

Comment: Since the FixedUpdate is not called as frequently as the Update, the Input detection may be proccessed. Move the input detection into the Update function and set a boolean to true. In the FixedUpdate, check the boolean and set it back to false when casting the ray.

Comment: do u guys know how to delete the food the raycast picks up

Comment: @FatihTkale If you were able to find a good solution to your problem, consider posting your own answer to your question. And if you have further questions not related to the original...post a new question to the site, but only after you've done your requisite research and are certain your can't solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **LayerMasks** to achieve what you're trying to do : this way you can save performances while being sure not to raycast undesired items.
Also note you can use `Debug.DrawRay()` to display your raycast in *Scene view*.